# Building registration feature in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a register and login program in java. Since I'm new to java, I'm not sure of what to use for the register part. Do they have struct like C++ to store the account's info? Or a similar and simple method which can do this?

Also, right now I'm trying out the array method, that means each time user entered the required information, it'll store each value into the appropriate array. For example a

```
final Vector<String>[] usernameV = (Vector<String>[]) new Vector [100];
```

after reading input from the username text field

```
usernameIn = usernameField.getText();
```

the value will be stored into the vector

```
usernameV[i].add(usernameIn);
```

However, what can I use if I have getPassword(); to store the input password from JPasswordField?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, please don't do this.

Comment: @duffymo and do what instead?

Comment: If you are familiar with C++, then you know that its classes as structs are nearly identical. Java only has classes.

Comment: Anything but that data structure.  It's a Java "don't".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analogous thing to struct in Java is class (often a "bean" for value objects). So you could have

```
class User {
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

to mimic a struct. Although more common would be the bean

```
class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    // getPassword and setPassword similar
}
```

This is verbose, but provides some extra encapsulation because the world outside the class depends on the methods, not their implementation as private variables.

Then your user "database" could be a Map.

```
HashMap<String,User> allUsersByName = new HashMap<String,User>();

// store a new user or update
allUsersByName.put(username, user);

// look up a user
allUsersByName.get(user);
```

Usually user databases need to persist across application restart, so you would use a relational database and some ORM library like Hibernate or you would be writing manual data access code to turn the above into "SELECT" and "INSERT" in your users table.

And good security practice would store a salt and value of a one-way cryptographic hash function on username + salt. But that's another story - the question was just what to use in the place of struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string[][] and and do like

```
string[0][0] = "user1"
string[0][1] = "password1"
string[1][0] = "user2"
string[1][1] = "password2"
```

You're new to java but you can try HashMaps which is easier to this question but harder to implement at first.

Look here http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/how-to-use-of-hashmap.html

Comment: Storing passwords in plaintext. ***Great*** idea.... Also, array indeces start with 0.

Comment: Not many will steal a car without wheels, I believe his test is based on local program with no internet access. Of course, you can always easily make a program to encrypt all passwords and move them to a more secure location if needed. I do not see any problem with what he is trying to do. Also, why would you downvote him, he proposed a solution and a reference.

Comment: @Dmitry before his edit he had array indeces starting from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a simpler way to store the username and password data. When a user submit the registration form, it'll output into a text file

```
private class submitListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            String newEmail, newUser, systemMsg;
            char[] newPass;
            char[] confirmNewPass;

            newEmail = emailField.getText();
            newUser = usernameField.getText();
            newPass = passwordField.getPassword();
            confirmNewPass = confirmPassField.getPassword();

            String strPass = new String(newPass);
            String strConfPass = new String(confirmNewPass);
            if(strPass.equals(strConfPass) && !newEmail.isEmpty() && !newUser.isEmpty() && 
                    !strPass.isEmpty()){
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Data.txt", true));
                BufferedWriter emailOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("email.txt", true));
                out.write(newUser);
                out.write("\t\t");
                out.write(newPass);
                out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                emailOut.write(newEmail);
                emailOut.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                systemMsg = "New account created, please log in.";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, systemMsg);
                ((CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout()).show(cardPanel, "login");
                emailField.setText(null);
                usernameField.setText(null);
                passwordField.setText(null);
                confirmPassField.setText(null);
                out.close();
                emailOut.close();
            }
            else{
                systemMsg = "Please enter the missing information.";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, systemMsg);
            }
        }catch(IOException E){}
    }
}
```

and then it'll compare the login information with these existing text file like this:

```
private class LoginListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String username, inUsername, inPass, str = "Incorrect username or password.";
        char[] password;

        username = usernameField.getText();
        password = passwordField.getPassword();
        //Convert char to str
        String convertPass = new String(password);

        try {
            fileScan = new Scanner(new File("Data.txt"));
        }catch(Exception err){}

        while(fileScan.hasNext()){
            inUsername = fileScan.next();
            inPass = fileScan.next();
            if(username.equals(inUsername) && convertPass.equals(inPass)){
                ((CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout()).show(cardPanel, "main");
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);   
            usernameField.setText(null);
            passwordField.setText(null);
        }
        fileScan.close();
    }
}
```

but when I run the program, it keeps reporting wrong username or password even though they're correct. How to fix this?